# Why does the struct parameterless constructor have to be public C#

Tags: c#, struct

```
struct plane {
    public int first;
    public int second = 5;

    public plane() { //has to be public
        //first = 99; error, all uninitialized instance fields must be initialized
    }

    plane(int h) { //can be private
        //first = 88; error, all uninitialized instance fields must be initialized
    }

}
```

I am trying to understand the whole concept of struct initialization:
I am sorry but I need to ask 2 questions because I think they are very dependent on eacg other:

Why does the parameterless constructor have to be public? I assume It is because the implicit constructor is public but this reason is just not enough to explain it.

 why do we HAVE to initialize all the non-static uninitialized fields? I mean we could do it later manually.

Comment: Non-compiler-generated parameterless constructors for structs is a _very_ new thing (they have traditionally not been allowed). You may finde this interesting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/parameterless-struct-constructors. I expect the initialization requirement has to do with changing the world, but keeping the pre-conditions the same. In the old world, you knew that `var s=new MyStruct();` would give you a fully initialized struct. If you don't fully initialize the object, who should?

Comment: What you are saying is version dependent and original language definition do not allow explicit parameterless constructor.

Comment: This might be of interest as well [Structure types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) that does try to cover both of your questions (maybe not with enough explanation) and [Struct Design (guidelines)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct) that gives an idea why some (self-imposed) limitations are good, for example not providing a parameterless constructor for a struct "allows arrays of structs to be created without having to run the constructor on each item of the array".

Comment: @Flydog57, Okay I see the point. Thank you, explains a lot. I read some of the materials and I think I understand why we have to initialize all the non-static uninitialized fields but I still can not understand why the explicit parameterless constructor has to be public.

Comment: `why do we HAVE to initialize all the non-static uninitialized fields?` [This is going to be fixed in C# 11](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5737)

Comment: Here are the pertinent bits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#struct-initialization-and-default-values